# How to pass data by Back Button, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, back-button

There are several answers on the site, but it looks like I need a more clear answer.

Assume Activity1 contains a TextView and Activity2 contains a RecyclerView. If some data on Activity2 is modified, Activity1 should be informed. There are two ways to Activity1 from Activity2:

1. A normal button on the layout.
2. "The" Back Button.

It looks possible to call `startActivity()` with `putExtra()` inside `onBackPressed()`. However this does not look efficient to me, as it will reload the UI, reload data, restart initial checks etc. Therefore, I'd like to send a flag so that "only the essential" changes can be made in Activity1 -by decoding the flag with an `if` statement in `onStart()` I suppose(?). How do I achieve this with both buttons.

Bonus question:

1. It is possible to use sharedPreferences to transfer data.
2. It is possible to use a common class to transfer data.

Is using a common class faster than sharedPreferences, especially if I need to transfer data often? I read something like: "once sharedPreferences is loaded into RAM it is in the RAM till the closing of the app, so it is not that slow."
Also, is using common class robust enough to handle unexpected behavior like closing the app suddenly, or receiving a call etc.?

Comment: Search for startActivityForResult.

Answer (score 0):

You can start Activity2 using `startActivityForResult` and then call `setResult` to return a value.

Or you can use a `ViewModel` (common class) to share data between activities.
The difference between a using a variable in a `ViewModel` and saving data to `SharedPreferences` is that the variables in a `ViewModel` are not persisted and the information will be lost when the app is closed.

Comment: Thank you. What if user jumps to Activity3 from Activity2? Will `onActivitResult()` be triggered for Activity1? Also would you give a simpler example than [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) page? How to return a `DataChanged` flag to Activity 1. In what part of Activity2 should the result be defined?

Comment: You have to call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);` in Activity2, when `onBackPressed` is called. No, it won't be triggered if you have 3 activities, I recommend you to use a `ViewModel ` in that case

Comment: Actually I have a transfer structure that depends on `sharedPreferences`. But this structure reqires that everytime Activity1 restarts I load an ArrayList in JSON form. Maybe it is better to write flags into sP, check only the flags and pull the whole list only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

pass and get data into multiple activity for this i recommend you to use the shared preference to get and set the data into multiple activity. and you can also use to local storage. but if you are using 2 activity than you can use on activity Result .

Comment: Thanks. I also used sharedPreferences. But everytime activity1 starts I load a list from sharedPreferences, which does not look so efficient. Maybe it is better to store flags into sharedPreferences and load the list only if necessary.

Comment: you can use realm to store the data from server its essay

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there an open-source alternative?